# React Router 4: Internal Navigation Changes URL But Not View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am pretty new to React and have gotten stuck on a React Router 4 issue that I can not solve, even after looking through all of the issues on this topic. I have a navigation section in the middle of my page that should switch the view on the bottom of the page depending on what I have clicked. When I click a new section in my navbar the url changes to the correct thing but my view does not update and instead is just left blank. Is there something wrong with my code causing this issue? See below:

My main navbar at the top of the page (which works) can be seen here:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Menu, Container, Button, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { NavLink, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu inverted fixed="top">
        <Container>
          <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/" header>
            <Icon name="angle double up" size="big" />
            Atlas
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item as={NavLink} to="/profile" name="Profile" />
          <Menu.Item as={NavLink} to="/budget" name="Budget" />
          <Menu.Item position="right">
            <Button as={Link} to="/settings" color="brown" animated="vertical">
              <Button.Content hidden>Settings</Button.Content>
              <Button.Content visible>
                <Icon name="setting" />
              </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button as={Link} to="/proSignUp" color="brown" animated="fade">
              <Button.Content visible>Sign-up for a Pro Account</Button.Content>
              <Button.Content hidden>$5 a month</Button.Content>
            </Button>
          </Menu.Item>
        </Container>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

My App.jsx file (which works) which contains the navbar and routes:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ProfileDashboard from "../../features/profile/ProfileDashboard/ProfileDashboard";
import NavBar from "../../features/nav/NavBar/NavBar";
import HomePage from "../../features/home/HomePage";
import BudgetDashboard from "../../features/budget/BudgetDashboard/BudgetDashboard";
import SettingsPage from "../../features/settings/Settings"
import ProSignUp from "../../features/proSignUp/ProSignUp";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>

        <Route
          path="/(.+)"
          render={() => (
            <div>
              <NavBar />
              <Container className="main">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/profile" component={ProfileDashboard} />
                  <Route path="/budget" component={BudgetDashboard} />
                  <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsPage} />
                  <Route path="/proSignUp" component={ProSignUp} />
                </Switch>
              </Container>
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Profile Page navbar (which is changing routes) can be seen here:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProfileNav = () => {
  return (
    <Grid.Column width={16}>
      <Menu horizontal="true" secondary>
        <Menu.Item as={NavLink} to="/profile/overview">Overview</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as={NavLink} to="/profile/analytics">Analytics</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </Grid.Column>
  );
};

export default withRouter(ProfileNav);
```

And finally, my ProfileDashboard (which doesn't work) which contains my profile nav bar and routes can be seen below:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Grid, Divider } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import ProfileHeader from "../ProfileHeader/ProfileHeader";
import ProfileNav from "../ProfileNav/ProfileNav";
import ProfileList from "../ProfileList/ProfileList";
import ProfileAnalytics from "../ProfileAnalytics/ProfileAnalytics";

const contentHash = {
  headerContent: [
    {
      title: "Demographics",
      age: 21,
      sex: "male",
      location: "Tucky, KY"
    },
    {
      title: "Profession",
      jobTitle: "Event Coordinator",
      employer: "Tucky Tuck",
      experience: "5 years",
      preTaxIncome: 62000,
      postTaxIncome: 44000
    },
    {
      title: "Investments",
      highRisk: "blah blah",
      mediumRisk: "blah blah",
      lowRisk: "blah blah"
    },
    {
      title: "Retirement",
      "401k": 415000,
      RothIRA: 61000
    }
  ]
};

class ProfileDashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={16}>
          <ProfileHeader headerContent={contentHash.headerContent} />
          <Divider />
          <ProfileNav />
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/profile" to="/profile/overview" />
            <Route path="profile/overview" component={ProfileList} />
            <Route path="profile/analytics" component={ProfileAnalytics} />
          </Switch>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default ProfileDashboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a lot of trial and error. I had to put both the components I was switching between inside a new component for the routing to work. So I made a new ProfileFooter component that held all of the routing logic and switched between the ProfileList and ProfileAnalytics page.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import ProfileList from "../ProfileList/ProfileList";
import ProfileAnalytics from "../ProfileAnalytics/ProfileAnalytics";

class ProfileFooter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/profile" to="/profile/overview" />
          <Route path="/profile/overview" component={ProfileList} />
          <Route path="/profile/analytics" component={ProfileAnalytics} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProfileFooter;
```